# Append not showing on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am experiencing a problem with append.

I add a div using append.

the chrome browser running, but not in firefox.

The following code append (formatted code):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
$j('#slider').nivoSlider();

$j("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){

    $j(this).addClass("hover");
    $j('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

}, function(){

    $j(this).removeClass("hover");
    $j('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

});

$j("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

$checkParent = $j('.menu-treatment .wpcf7-checkbox');
$checkParent.find('span').mouseover(function() {
    $j(this).find('.tooltip').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    $j(this).find('.tooltip2').stop(true, true).fadeIn();

    $j(this).mouseleave(function(){
        $j(this).find('.tooltip').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        $j(this).find('.tooltip2').stop(true, true).fadeOut();

    })
})
$checkParent.find('.wpcf7-list-item:first-child').append('<div class="tooltip" style="display: none;">Tune your body, mind, soul, and emotion with the ancient Tibetan Singing Bowl <div class="panah-kiri"></div></div>');

});
```

Comment: Dunno why you flag this with php, but ok. append is a jQuery function, did you include the library?

Comment: sorry for that, I already include library 1.7.2

Comment: Can you provide the whole sourcecode? I cant see the error and im too lazy to write a testcode myself now.

Comment: thats my full code, pls help :(

Comment: Code seems to work for me ... which version of firefox do you have?

Comment: my firefox version 25.0
What version you are using?

Comment: 25 too. Guess it wouldnt be bad if you include the HTML too, i just created a small piece myself and got no problems with it.

Comment: I added it in the html form. the form of a wordpress plugin contact form 7. successful in all browsers except firefox. What version you are using jquery?

Comment: 1.10.2, but i dont think that its the problem of the library because it works in all other browsers. Im afraid that i cant solve this problem, i dont have any problems with the code. :3

Comment: i found soulution. before I use jquery version 1.5.2 but after using the latest version successfully. thanks helpful :)